# Cannot insert JavaScript code into a R shiny.semantic app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am having issues inserting a javascript code into a Shiny app (clicking/unclicking the `All` box should check/uncheck all the boxes).

**app.R**

```
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- semanticPage(
    multiple_checkbox(input_id = "myCheckbox",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c("All", "A", "B"),
                      class = "customCheckbox"),
    
    includeScript(path = "www/myscript.js"),
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**myscript.js**

```
$(".customCheckbox input[value='All']").click(function(e) {
  $(".customCheckbox input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(e.target).prop("checked"));
});
```

I know that the `javascript` code works as shown below.

```js
$(".customCheckbox input[value='All']").click(function(e) {
  $(".customCheckbox input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(e.target).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui form grouped fields ss-checkbox-input customCheckbox" id="myCheckbox">
  <label for="myCheckbox"></label>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox  ">
      <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" tabindex="0" value="All"/>
      <label>All</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox  ">
      <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" tabindex="0" value="A"/>
      <label>A</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox  ">
      <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" tabindex="0" value="B"/>
      <label>B</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried different ways to insert the javascript code into the Shiny app.

**app_2.R**

```
library(shiny.semantic)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- semanticPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    multiple_checkbox(input_id = "myCheckbox",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c("All", "A", "B"),
                      class = "customCheckbox")
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    runjs(HTML("
        $(\".customCheckbox input[value='All']\").click(function(e) {
            $(\".customCheckbox input[type='checkbox']\").prop('checked', $(e.target).prop(\"checked\"));
        });
    "))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**app_3.R**

```
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- semanticPage(
    tags$script(src = "myscript.js"),
    # OR 
    #tags$head(tags$script(src = "myscript.js"))
    
    multiple_checkbox(input_id = "myCheckbox",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c("All", "A", "B"),
                      class = "customCheckbox")
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit**

When using `shiny::fluidPage` instead of `shiny.semantic::semanticPage`, everything works fine. However I would need to stick to `shiny.semantic`.

```
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- fluidPage(
    multiple_checkbox(input_id = "myCheckbox",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c("All", "A", "B"),
                      class = "customCheckbox"),
    includeScript(path = "www/myscript.js"),
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your app_2.R runs fine for me.  Perhaps you just need to restart RStudio.

Comment: @YBS I tried restarting RStudio with no luck. I noticed though that the problem comes from `ui <- semanticPage(...)`. The JS script works fine when using `ui <- fluidPage(...)` instead (see edit). I use `shinyjs_1.1`, `shiny.semantic_0.4.3` and `shiny_1.5.0`.

Comment: I have `shinyjs_2.0` and `shiny.semantic_0.4.0`. Same Shiny.

Comment: @YBS Fitting your packages version did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a workaround by removing the `hidden` class of the `All` box.

```
library(shiny.semantic)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- semanticPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    multiple_checkbox(input_id = "myCheckbox",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c("All", "A", "B"),
                      class = "customCheckbox")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    runjs(HTML("
        $(\".customCheckbox input[value='All']\").removeClass(\"hidden\");
        
        $(\".customCheckbox input[value='All']\").click(function(e) {
            $(\".customCheckbox input[type='checkbox']\").prop('checked', $(e.target).prop(\"checked\"));
        });
    "))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```